iag-grid data is not refreshing when i change the data from an external component
my aggrid is getting its data from a pinia store, bras is an array of the customer's branches
const {  selectedCustomer } = storeToRefs(customerStore)
const rowData =selectedCustomer.value.bras

when i modify the data of a branch in another component that also draws from this store, the grid is not being updated and the whole thing kind of glitches. Has anyone encountered this before?

You need to mutate the state within the store itself, not just a variable that "draws from" the store. Without being able to see your code, it's impossible to tell you exactly what's wrong. Please modify your question to include all the relevant code. As a side note, "bras" is a dreadful abbreviation of "branches". Here's the Pinia docs for mutating the state in a store. https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/state.html#Mutating-the-state
